# How does Torch broadcasting work for (8, 8) @ (4, 8, 2)?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I have tensors of sizes:

```
a.shape 
=> (8, 8)
b.shape 
=> (4, 8, 2)

c = a @ b 
c.shape
=> (4, 8, 2)
```

I am surprised to see that `a @ b` is broadcast-able. I went through pytorch's broadcasting rules and it seems like these shouldn't be compatible.

Can someone walk through how this is being calculated?

Comment: `(8,8) @ (8,2)` is normal 2d matrix multiply producing (8,2).  Only the `4` is `broadcasted`, result is `(4,8,2)`.  Only the leading dimensions of 3d (or higher) are `broadcasted`.  The last 2 are `dot`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the docs for [torch.matmul](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html)

In this case, `b` is interpreted as a batched matrix with the first axis being the batch dimension.